# Can the lodash zip function work with an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

The lodash [zip()](https://lodash.com/docs#zip) function normally accepts two or more arrays as arguments. Can it accept an array of arrays?

For example, given an object like `var aa = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];` and a desired output of `[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]` zip() must be called like `_.zip(aa[0],aa[1])`. For an array of arrays with more than two elements, typing the indexes into the function call becomes repetitive.

Calling `_.zip(aa)` doesn't work. It just nests the original array of arrays.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can splat your array of arrays using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or the ES2015 [`spread` operator (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
// call zip with a `this` context of the lodash object
// and with each entry in aa as a separate argument
// e. g. zip(aa[0], aa[1], ..., aa[N]);
_.zip.apply(_, aa);

// Same call, but using ES2015
_.zip(...aa)
```

Comment: This is an important note about the right context to pass. It might sometimes work to pass `null` but the lodash object is the obviously right choice.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, try this:

```
_.zip.apply(_, aa)
```